# Sencha touch nested navigation view

Tags: navigation, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

[image]

In my app, I have a **Home** page that has the following menu buttons:

```
1. Button1
2. Button2
3. Button3
4. Button4
```

Now When I tap ***Button1***, the app navigates to ***Page1***. (Page1 is a navigation view).

Problem here is, by default ***Page1*** does not have a Back button to move back to ***Home*** page. So i have to manually add a Back button.

***Question 1***: Is there another way to push the Page1 view into the Home View so that the Back button is auto generated?

Ok, So now I manually added the Back button on ***Page1***. This ***Page1*** is a navigation view having a list. On clicking the list item, it moves to **SubPage1** .

Now the problem here is, there is a default back button that will be generated + the manual back button that I added. So **2 back buttons** !!

To solve this, I hide the manually added back button on push. And then show the button on pop. Again the issue with this is, there is a slight delay in hide/show and this is visible in the app. Another problem with this is, in older models of Blackberry, the manually added Back button does not get hidden sometimes !!!

***Question 2***: Any better way to handle this !?

Finally, What If i want nested navigation view?

Say, I have a store with 10 records.
In Page 1, i display 3 records as a list -

```
record1 - on tap of this, show its detailed view
record2 - on tap of this, show its detailed view
record3 - on tap of this, show another sub list with records 4 to 10.
```

***Question 3***: How do i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: Yes, you can use a NavigationView as main page. Then push it your home. On button tap event, push it your Page1 view (which is a list, and not a navigation view anymore).
If needed, hide the navigationBar on your home page by listening to push and pop events of your navigation view.

Question 2: My first answer solves your problem

Question 3: You can use the listpaging plugin for your list. Check it to see if it meets your needs : http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.plugin.ListPaging

Comment: thanks @Alytrem. Never thought of that approach for q1 and q2.

where as ListPaging is not what i'm looking for